# Win7 service with HTTPListener stops responding after one request

Tags: c#, http, windows-7, service, listener

I'm a novice c# developer - trying to write a simple win7 service. 
The service should start HTTPListener and listen for incoming browser requests, when a request is received it returns a response and continue to listen for additional requests.
I don't need to deal with parallelism since there would be no more than one request at a time (and very short).

I used the following code, but after the first response the service stops responding.
I may need a loop somewhere but I am not familiar with the API so I may also be wrong with what I'm doing.

Thank you for your help.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:9999/");
        listener.Start();

        listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(OnRequestReceive), listener);
     }

    private void OnRequestReceive(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
        byte[] buff = {1,2,3};

        response.Close(buff, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there!  After receiving one request, you need to start listening for another one.

```
private void OnRequestReceive(IAsyncResult result) 
{ 
    HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState; 

    HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result); 
    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response; 
    byte[] buff = {1,2,3}; 

    response.Close(buff, true); 

    // ---> start listening for another request
    listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(OnRequestReceive), listener); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Working like magic. So many hours of frustration over one line of code :)